# How to remove event listener from Vue Component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, components, vue-component

I have a Vue2 component which contains an added eventListener i created on `mounted`. I was wondering how do i properly remove this listener when the component is destroyed?

```
<template>
    <div>
      ...
    </div>
  </template>
  
  <script>
  export default {
    mounted() {
        window.addEventListener('click', (evt) => {
          this.handleClickEvent(evt)
        })
    },
    destroyed() {
      //   window.removeEventListener('click', ????);
    },
    methods: {
      handleClickEvent(evt) {
        // do stuff with (evt) 
      },
    },
  }
  </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `this.$el` for whole component and destroy event like you created it:

```js
Vue.component('Child', {
  template: `
    <div class="child">
      click for event
    </div>
  `,
  mounted() {
    this.$el.addEventListener('click', (evt) => {
      this.handleClickEvent(evt)
    })
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
    console.log('distroyed')
    this.$el.removeEventListener('click', (evt) => {
      this.handleClickEvent(evt)
    })
  },
  methods: {
    handleClickEvent(evt) {
      console.log(evt.currentTarget)
      // do stuff with (evt) 
    },
  },
})


new Vue({
  el: "#demo",
  data() {
    return {
      show: true
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggleShow() {
      this.show = !this.show
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.child {
  height: 150px;
  width: 200px;
  background: goldenrod;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <div>
    <button @click="toggleShow">mount/unmount component</button>
    <Child v-if="show" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't think this works, you are calling removeEventListener with a newly created function, not the original one.

Answer (score 4):

You have to keep a reference to the registered click handler, in order to be able to remove it later:

```js
mounted() {
  this.clickHandler = () => { ... };
  window.addEventListener('click', this.clickHandler);
}

beforeDestroy() {
  window.removeEventListener('click', this.clickHandler);
}
```

However, you seem to already have this function defined in the component. It's named `handleClickEvent`. So there's no reason to create an arrow function wrapper around it. You can use it directly:

```js
mounted() {
  window.addEventListener('click', this.handleClickEvent);
}

beforeDestroy() {
  window.removeEventListener('click', this.handleClickEvent);
}
```

Another neat feature available in vue2 (and, sadly, not in vue3) is to dynamically register a hook, which allows adding and removing the handler in `mounted()`, without the need of keeping a reference to it in the component:

```js
mounted() {
  const handler = () => { ... }; // local variable
  window.addEventListener('click', handler);
  this.$once('hook:beforeDestroy',
    () => window.removeEventListener('click', handler)
  );
}
```

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Programmatic-Event-Listeners