# How to work with EventListeners for draggable scrolling?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, event-listener

I'm trying to build a calendar in which you can scroll. I would like to achieve the scrolling also by dragging. So I use EventListeners.

`mousemove` continuously triggers, after the first `mousedown`, even if I already released the mouse. So the removeEventListeners don't really work. I don't quite understand what's wrong or how to get the interactions between all Listeners to work correctly.

Here is my [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/musing-dew-cwch8l?file=%2Fpages%2Findex.vue&selection=%5B%7B%22endColumn%22%3A2%2C%22endLineNumber%22%3A87%2C%22startColumn%22%3A2%2C%22startLineNumber%22%3A87%7D%5D&workspace=%257B%2522activeFileId%2522%253A%2522cl8vrblj0000alsgzes9vcu2n%2522%252C%2522openFiles%2522%253A%255B%2522%252Fpages%252Findex.vue%2522%255D%252C%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522gitSidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522COMMIT%2522%252C%2522sidekickItems%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PREVIEW%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A3000%252C%2522key%2522%253A%2522cl9ebgcvh000k3b6huhays636%2522%252C%2522isMinimized%2522%253Afalse%257D%255D%257D)

```js
  mounted() {
    this.initScrollCalendar()
  },

  methods: {
    initScrollCalendar() {
      const calendar = this.$refs.calendar
      calendar.scrollLeft = this.position.left;

      calendar.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => this.mouseDownHandler())
    },

    mouseDownHandler() {
      const calendar = this.$refs.calendar      
      calendar.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => this.mouseMoveHandler(e) )
      calendar.addEventListener('mouseup', this.mouseUpHandler());
    },

    mouseMoveHandler(e) {
      console.log("Move")
      const calendar = this.$refs.calendar 
      const rect = calendar.getBoundingClientRect()
      const clientX = e.clientX - rect.left
      
      const dx = clientX - this.position.x
      calendar.scrollLeft = this.position.left + dx
    },

    mouseUpHandler() {
      console.log("Up")
      const calendar = this.$refs.calendar 
      calendar.removeEventListener('mousemove', (e) => this.mouseMoveHandler(e));
      calendar.removeEventListener('mouseup', this.mouseUpHandler());
    }
  }
```

Comment: You can probably use some baked-in listerners like `@mousemove`. But if you want to do them all vanilla, then you will need to remove them inside of the `beforeDestoy` hook like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70726573/8816585

Comment: Here are more details about that hook: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#beforeDestroy Also, you could either target the element again or maybe store it's id in an upper scope for an easier reference. I guess the 2nd approach is better overall.

Comment: Be also careful because if you don't remove those listeners, you will have quite some memory leaks too!

Comment: Thanks! The problem with `@mousemove` alone is, that it's react continuously  on mousemovements of course. It should only triggers if the mouse is pressed down. I could use `@mousedown` and add the `mousemove`-listener in the method. I will do this for now and see how I go on. Or can I achieve my plan only with baked-in listeners too? However, I wonder how I can trigger mousemove only on mousedown then.

Comment: Yeah I've already nuked my app with the listeners :P

Comment: Not sure but there is maybe a possible combo with both. There is maybe a package doing a wrapper for that purpose (like Hammer or alike, checking if you're doing a drag and drop kind of action). Otherwise, vanilla is also feasible.

Comment: I wouldn't like to load one more package. So vanilla would most likely be the best way for me. However, removing the listeners in beforeDestroy is also not the solution I'm looking for, because it's only triggered before I leave the page. I want to remove the listeners immediately at `mouseup` ...

Comment: Why? You should not add/remove them all the time. Getting to know if you're above your element should be mainly enough. Something like the point 16 here: https://dev.to/michaelthiessen/25-vue-tips-you-need-to-know-2h70

Comment: I wouldn’t know how to. I posted a sandbox for demonstration.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using [vue-dragscroll](https://vue-dragscroll.donfalcon.com/). Works like a charm and the setup is totally simple. If needed, I can also set a starting position of my scroll container.

Don't forget `overflow: auto` in css

```html
<div ref="scrollContainer" v-dragscroll>
  ...
</div>
```

```js
// Setting starting point
const scrollContainer = this.$refs.scrollContainer
scrollContainer.scrollLeft = 500;
```

Comment: Hehe, still used a package.

Comment: I would have loved to make it myself, but I have to move forward... :D